# How to remove | of Html Script while page is loading per ajax (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I want to know how I can remove those disturbing `|` special chars in my Script.

Example Html:

```
<a name="1">&nbsp;</a><br>|<b>5.11. Monday</b> |
```

This is only an example they are all over the code some sort of menu Dividers.

Im loading the Page per Ajax in a wrapper and i want to manipulate it there eg removing the menu the only problem is that there are no classes or id with which i can work with so i have to find a solution which is searching for them all.

All these are stored in a div with the class="main"

Comment: You don't have access to the html you're loading?

Comment: Why not using replace()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `replace` with a global regex (modifier `g`). Just note that you need to escape the pipe because it's a regex meta character:

```
str = str.replace(/\|/g, '');
```

The forward-slashes are just delimiters, `\|` is the literal pipe, and `g` makes sure that **all** occurrences are replaced.